# Structural break test for non-stationary time series

Tags: r, time-series, stationarity, structural-change

I recently found out that Bai and Perron test for identifying structural breaks using the package `strucchange` can't be used in case time series is non stationary. Is anyone aware of a R package that can be used to identify structural breaks for non stationary time series. I did find some papers but could not find a R program.